# Garbage collection in python module

Tags: python, callback, ctypes

I am using a very simple ctypes module:

```
% cat acme/__init__.py
from acme import lowlevel
```

and

```
% cat acme/lowlevel.py
import logging
_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("libacme.so.0")
def _func(name, restype, argtypes):
    func = getattr(_lib, name)
    func.restype = restype
    func.argtypes = argtypes
    return func

def py_log_func(a, b, c):
    log_levels = {
        1: logging.DEBUG,
        2: logging.INFO,
        3: logging.WARNING,
        4: logging.ERROR,
        5: logging.CRITICAL,
    }
    log = logging.getLogger(b)
    log.log(log_levels[a], c)
    return

LOGFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_int, c_char_p, c_char_p)
acme_log_listener_configure = _func("acme_log_listener_configure", None, [LOGFUNC])
# setup default listener:
acme_log_listener_configure(LOGFUNC(py_log_func))
```

For any experienced python developer the error is quite obvious. So my question is: is the current fix the correct one:

```
# store at module level the log function to prevent python from doing garbage
# collection on the function:
PY_LOG_FUNC = LOGFUNC(py_log_func)
# setup default listener:
acme_log_listener_configure(PY_LOG_FUNC)
```

In other word `PY_LOG_FUNC` is guarantee to have a single value throughout the python process lifetime ?

---

Per documentation:

> Make sure you keep references to CFUNCTYPE() objects as long as they
> are used from C code. ctypes doesn’t, and if you don’t, they may be
> garbage collected, crashing your program when a callback is made.

ref:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't reassign `PY_LOG_FUNC` and it doesn't go out of scope it won't change.
Your fix works.

Here's an alternative.  Decorate the Python function with the C callback signature.  the decorator is the same as coding `py_log_func = LOGFUNC(py_log_func)` so it redefines the Python function name **as** the C callback so it is in-scope as long as the function exists.

```py
LOGFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_int, c_char_p, c_char_p)

@LOGFUNC
def py_log_func(a, b, c):
    ...

...
acme_log_listener_configure(py_log_func)
```